# Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock, Round Table

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The question I have is can you order all the elements around a round table such that for each element the members on the left side are inferior and the members on the right side are superior (when seated at the table, facing inward).

I believe the answer is yes. But I want a formal proof for it.

**ETA: The final answer is NO, Barry Cipra provided a counterexample with 7 elements.**

Example with 3, clockwise order: Paper Rock Scissors

Example with 5: Scissors Lizard Paper Spock Rock

Example with 9: Rock Scissors Spiderman Wizard Lizard Paper Glock Batman Spock

The general case has 2N+1 elements. For each element there are N inferior elements and N superior elements. Any element is equal to itself. Imagine a society where N is *huge*. For any individual 1/2 of everyone else is superior, and the other 1/2 is inferior. Note that the relationships *are* symmetric: If A is superior to B then B is inferior to A. Can you always distribute this huge population in a circle such that anyone to the left is inferior and anyone to the right is superior?

ETA: Here are some helpful images:

5 elements: http://www.linuxmotors.com/ScLiPaSpRo.jpg

9 elements: RPS9.jpg

15 elements: http://www.linuxmotors.com/RPS15.jpg

Similiar images are readily available with google image search. Most diagrams have the arrows going willy-nilly (some left, some right). My question is can the elements be reordered such that all the arrows go in the same direction.

Somehow to me it seems like a deep, interesting question, that would have a cool, easy proof.

Comment: Is there any other condition, like of $X$ is inferior to $Y$ then $Y$ is superior to $X$?

Comment: I had answered this incorrectly with a _no_ but I should have said _yes_. There is such a requirement. Sorry -- my bad!

Comment: @Thomas I figured out what I thought you were asking: If A is superior to B and B is superior to C, is it a requirement that C is superior to A? And in that case the answer _is_ no. But all pairs are symmetric.

Comment: It's definitely at heart a graph-theory problem. (Definitely not group theory.)

Comment: @dashxdr: Anti-symmetric.  If $A$ is inferior to $B$, then $B$ is necessarily superior to $B$.  (In plain terms, if paper beats rock, then rock loses to paper.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a counterexample with $2N+1=7$:

Suppose we have the (non-transitive) inequalities

> - Rock < Paper < Scissors < Rock

as usual, and

> - Batman < Superman < Aquaman < Batman.

Let's interleave these with

> - Rock < Batman < Paper, Scissors
> - Paper < Superman < Scissors, Rock
> - Scissors < Aquaman < Rock, Paper

At this point, Rock, Paper, and Scissors are each inferior to two others and superior to three, while Batman, Superman, and Aquaman are each superior to two others and inferior to three.

Now add a Wizard with inequalities

> - Rock, Paper, Scissors < Wizard < Batman, Superman, Aquaman

Now *everyone* is inferior to three and superior to three.

Wherever the Wizard sits, Rock, Paper, and Scissors must be to his left (and Batman, Superman, and Aquaman to his right, but it suffices to look at just one side).  If the desired condition were satisfied, then whichever one is seated to Wizard's immediate left would have to be superior to *both* the other two.  But that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you mean by "inferior" and "superior". It is trivial to arrange things so that $x$ is always "superior" to its predecessor and "inferior" to its successor, going around a circle: just put the elements in a circle, and *define* inferior = to the left of $x$ and superior = to the right of $x$.

The problem is, this relationship is not transitive: if $a$ is inferior to $b$, and $b$ is inferior to $c$, but it does not follow that $a$ is inferior to $c$. In fact with a circular arrangement, this cannot always hold. Thus I may be able to beat the guy on my left, but who is to say if I can beat the guy on his left?

Such non-transitive relationships have properties that are occasionally useful. After, that is exactly why we have "rock, paper, scissors". If rock always won, it would be pointless. But usually, transitive relationships are much richer.

Comment: I know the case of elements ordered in a circle satisfies the requirement. What I'm wondering is can you _always_ arrange the members in a circle if there are 2N+1 members and each member is superior to N others and inferior to N others. I'm trying to visualize a proof.

Comment: He states in the problem what the conditions are, though it is buried in the last paragraph after a lot of noise. Basically, you have $2N+1$ elements, and each element has $N$ others it considers inferior and $N$ others it considers superior. Per OPs comment to my question, there is no known symmetry, either - if $X$ thinks it is superior to $Y$, $Y$ does not think it is inferior to $X$.

Comment: Again just to be complete there _is_ a symmetry requirement for all pairs. If X>Y then Y<X.